# MVC, Only search for controller in root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

From my controller in the area Admin I call, through my view, my _MasterLayout.cshtml in root. The "_MasterLayout.cshtml" have this code:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Top", "Module", new {area=""});}
```

The problem is that it finds multiple controllers with the same name, one in root and one in area Admin. How do I limit the search for that controller to just root?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the namespace parameter to RegisterRoutes in Global.asax and in RegisterArea in your AreaRegistrations?

Like this

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "Your.Admin.Namespace.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

And this in Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new[] { "Default.Namespace.Of.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.. (Fionn's answer will fix it)

But rather than just posting what fixed it for me... you might get more from reading this post

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx

The key part is `new[]{"AreasDemoWeb.Controllers"}`